# How to specify output path when using cmake -G?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to project files using CMake using `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15" .\src`. I would lie to specify an output directory (which should be created if doesn't exist. Something like: `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15" .\src -o .\build`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmake -B
```

-B            = Explicitly specify a build directory.